# Podemos criar a regra de negócio em nosso model?

Tags: c#, design-pattern

Qual melhor prática?

Criar a regra no próprio model ou criar uma outra classe

Ex:

```
public class Item
{
    public void Faturar()
    {
        //fatura item
    }
}

ou

public class ItemBLL
{
     public void Faturar(Item )
     {

     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, podemos criar regras de negócio no Model. Model representa o comportamento lógico dos dados na aplicação. Ele representa a lógica de negócios da aplicação.

Acredito que a resposta sobre criar a regra em uma classe ou em outra depende de qual o tipo de regra de negócio, pois dependendo da regra ela pode ou não ser criada dentro do objeto.

Exemplo 1: A regra de negócio abaixo é uma regra específica do objeto Item. Por esse motivo ela esta **implementada no próprio objeto**.

```
public class Item
{     
    public string NomeDoItem { get; set; }

    public void NomeDoItemDeveIniciarComLetra()
    {
        //Código que valida o nome do Item iniciado com letra
    }
}
```

Exemplo 2: Já para gerar uma Fatura, a regra de negócio pode ser diferente, dependendo do Item passado ou até mesmo de outro objeto. Por esse motivo essa regra de negócio pode ser **implementada em uma outra classe** que fará esse "serviço" de gerar a fatura de acordo com o Item.

```
public class ServicoFatura
{
    public void GerarFatura(Item item)
    {
        //Código que recebe um Item e gera a fatura 
    }

    public void ExcluirItemDaFatura(Item item)
    {
        //Código que recebe um Item
        //Verifica se o item possui Faturas geradas com valor maior que $1.000
        //Caso positivo retorna uma mensagem e não excluí o Item 
        //Além disso verifica se o Item possui suas faturas pagas
        if(item.PossuiFaturasGeradas() && item.FaturasGeradasPagas())
        {
            //...
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Analise o método **ExcluirItemDaFatura**, se essa regras fossem implementadas no objeto Item, no futuro caso necessário alterar `o valor da fatura` dessa regra de $1.000 para $2.000, seria necessário alteração no Item. Da mesma forma se fosse necessário alterar a regra do que seria uma `fatura gerada e paga`, teríamos também que alterar o Item. Com isso ficamos alterando o Item devido a mudanças relacionadas a fatura. Isso seria muito ruim: **O Item acabaria não tendo uma única responsabilidade e além de suas regras, ficaria carregando regras relacionadas a Fatura.**

Porém, se pensarmos bem sobre os termos destacados (exemplificando o que seria nossas regras de negócio) é possível identificar que elas tem relação com o Item, porém não são regras específicas do Item: o valor é da fatura, assim como a regra se ela foi paga e pode ser excluída. Então podemos retirar essa "sobrecarga" do Item, ficando este apenas com suas responsabilidades específicas e separar na classe ServicoFatura as regras específicas geração e exclusão de um item de uma fatura.

Comment: Entendi, então criando assim essa classe "Serviço" uma classe da camada BLL

Comment: @Rod Isso mesmo